# Entity Framework insert FK

Tags: c#

I have the following classes:

```
public class User
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }        
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}


public class Role
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string RoleName { get; set; }        
}
```

I would like to insert a new User:

```
var user = new User()
{
   Email = "jhon@gmail.com",                    
   Role = ?
 };


 db.Users.Add(user);
 db.SaveChanges();
```

How do I insert the `RoleId=1` as an `FK` ?

Comment: Have you tried using the `[ForeignKey]` attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a new role you would create special new role for that user like:

```
var role = new Role{
  RoleName = "Whatever"
} 

var user = new User(){
  Email = "jhon@gmail.com",
  Role = role
}
db.Users.Add(user);
db.SaveChanges();
```

If it is existing role and as you don't have navigation property would be best to fetch role from db to have db entity:

```
var role = db.Roles.Single(x => x.RoleName == "Whatever");
var user =  new User(){
   Email = "jhon@gmail.com",
   Role = role
 }
db.Users.Add(user);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing I noticed is that the User Class is missing the RoleId navigation property.

If you don't mind adding navigation property to your User class, you can make below changes to achieve it.

```
    public class User
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }        
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int RoleId {get;set;}
        [Required]
        public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    }
```

And now you can insert the User like this:

```
var user = new User()
{
   Email = "jhon@gmail.com",                    
   RoleId = db.Roles.Single(r => r.RoleName = "Role_Name").Select(x=>x.RoleId)
 };

db.Users.Add(user);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: In my case, EF automatically created the RoleId ('Role_Id') as FK in Users table. Adding the RoleId in the User class-object makes it more simple. now I can add the User roleId by just writing RoleId=1

Answer (score 0):

The `Identity` option specifies that the value will only be generated by the database when a value is first added to the database. Thereafter, the property will not be included in `UPDATE` statements by Entity Framework.

To conclude, you don't need to set `RoleId`, just create object with `RoleName` and add it to database.